# Standard property works, but dependency property doesn't in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following code behind, which works:

```
public DataTemplate ItemTemplate
{
    get { return _list.ItemTemplate; }
    set { _list.ItemTemplate = value; }
}
```

And I have the code, that I want to have, but it doesn't work. Even setter is never invoked:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemTemplateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemTemplate", typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(MyUserControl));
public DataTemplate ItemTemplate
{
    get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue(ItemTemplateProperty); }
    set
    {
        _list.ItemTemplate = value;
        SetValue(ItemTemplateProperty, value);
    }
}
```

The use of that is in XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<local:MyUserControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}"/>
```

Why the standard property works and dependency property doesn't?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the dependency property, .Net is doing something that's not obvious: it's accessing the dependency property identified by `ItemTemplateProperty` directly instead of using the `get` and `set` methods that you declared. The only difference, in this case, is that your `_list.ItemTemplate = value;` is never run.

When you use dependency properties, your getters and setters [should only contain the usual things](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613563.aspx#implications). Anything else will end up being confusing because WPF bypasses them when it uses the property.

If you need to set `_list.ItemTemplate` to the value, you should attach a static [`PropertyChangedCallback`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertychangedcallback.aspx) using the [other `DependencyProperty.Register` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597502.aspx). E.g.

```
private static void OnItemTemplateChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
    var uc = (MyUserControl)d;
    uc._list.ItemTemplate = (DataTemplate)e.NewValue;
}
```

Comment: Please also note the explanation given [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613563.aspx).

Comment: @Clemens Thanks, I've added that link (I was already saying the same thing, but a more authoritative professionally-written source is never a bad thing). =)

Answer (score 2):

DependencyProperty never invokes "Set" method, instead you will have to look for PropertyChanged event handler within creation of dependency property statement.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemTemplateProperty = 
   DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ItemTemplate", 
         typeof(DataTemplate), 
         typeof(MyUserControl),
         new FrameworkPropertyMetadata( 
             null, 
             new PropertyChangedCallback(ItemTemplateChanged) ));
public DataTemplate ItemTemplate
{
    get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue(ItemTemplateProperty); }
    set
    {
        _list.ItemTemplate = value;
        SetValue(ItemTemplateProperty, value);
    }
}

public static void ItemTemplateChanged(
   DependencyObject sender, 
   DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e){
   ((MyUserControl)sender).OnItemTemplateChanged(e);
}

protected void OnItemTemplateChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e){
    // you write your code here..
}
```